# "Source not found" when debugging SOME classes of the Android platform code

Tags: android, eclipse, android-source

I'm using Eclipse Kepler with the latest ADT, and I have already set the *Java Source Attachment* for android.jar to point to the correct directory.

With this setup, I can place breakpoints and step into **most** classes/methods with no problems at all. However, for **some** classes, Eclipse just refuses to load the source, and instead displays the standard *Source not found* screen, although the corresponding source file (ScrollBarDrawable.java) **is** present in the source directory (under `android\widget`).

The particular example I have now is with the `android.widget.ScrollBarDrawable` class, but it has happened with others before.

How to reproduce:

1. Create a simple project with an `EditText` in the layout.
2. Call `editText.setHorizontallyScrolling(true);` in `onCreate()` (so that it needs to draw scrollbars) and enter long text into it.
3. Place a breakpoint in the `onDrawScrollBars()` method of the `View` class, on any calls to methods of the `scrollBar` object (e.g. line 11967 for android-19).
4. Try to step into this method.

Has anyone else experienced this?

Any tips on how to fix it, or at least an explanation of why it might be happening (as in: this class is somewhat different from the others)? I have already trying added additional *File System Directory* entries to the *Edit Source Lookup Path* dialog, to no avail.

Comment: Have you checked the "search subfolders" checkbox in the debug source?

Comment: @Pankaj Yes, didn't make a difference unfortunately.